# How does an optionsCaption influence databinding in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have two nearly identical sets of code, the only difference between the two is that one has an options caption in a  element and the other does not. The code without the optionsCaption data binds seemingly correctly and the other appears to stop data binding after the first element is bound. Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong and why the data binding is working this way?

Example 1 - Does not work, in order to see, select one of the options - http://jsfiddle.net/749sj7w5/2/

Example 2 - Works correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/749sj7w5/3/

script:

```
var Program = function (programId, description) {
    this.ProgramId = programId;
    this.Description = description;
};


var myViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.program = ko.observable();
    self.programId = ko.observable(-1);

    self.availablePrograms = ko.observableArray([
    new Program(1, "Program One"),
    new Program(2, "Program Two"),
    new Program(3, "Program Three")]);

    self.programId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        self.program(self.availablePrograms()[newValue - 1]);
    });

};
```

non-working html:

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: availablePrograms, optionsText: 'Description', optionsValue: 'ProgramId', value: programId, optionsCaption: 'Select a Program'"></select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program().Description" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program().Description" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program().ProgramId" />
</div>
```

Working html:

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: availablePrograms, optionsText: 'Description', optionsValue: 'ProgramId', value: programId"></select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program().Description" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program().Description" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program().ProgramId" />
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to defend against `null` values if you use an `optionsCaption`, as `program()` will be `undefined` until something is selected. You can do the following:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/749sj7w5/4/)

```
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program() ? program().Description : 'none'" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program() ? program().Description : 'none'" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: program() ? program().ProgramId : 'none' " />
</div>
```

This will only evaluate the `program()` observable if it has been set.

Comment: True, but `program` value will be `undefined` not `null`.

Comment: @Tanner Thank you, I have a follow up question though. In the example where there is an optionsCaption, what exactly is happening when I select a program? If program() is null, then how is the first input element displaying a value after a program is selected, on the flip side, if program() is not null then how are the other two elements are not being bound?

Comment: @user2634253 A stab in the dark would be that when knockout initialises the input fields, it attempts to bind the first item and identifies that `program()` is `undefined`, but the binding is set, but with the subsequent attempts, it has already registered that it is `undefined`, so doesn't process the remaining items. That's a complete guess.

Comment: @user2634253 when knockout binds the first value, exception is thrown (because of `undefined`) and binding process stops. But this first binding stays "alive", and the rest are just not bound. That's why it behaves in such a weird way. BTW, look my answer for details on `what exactly is happening when I select a program`.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Okay, I think I finally understand. applyBindings gets called on the page load (correct?), an exception is thrown on the first binding, however the binding is applied. Since the binding is applied, but with an invalid object, that is why it updates later. The other two elements never had the binding applied, that is why they do not work when the program() is no longer undefined. Sorry for my slow uptake.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Glad you've figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

Browser console shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return program().Description }"
>   Message: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined

This happens because in first case (when doesn't work) the value of your `programId` doesn't change while knockout performs binding (since optionsCaption is specified and no actual value is selected). So `program` stays undefined, since you didn't initialize it with any value (`self.program = ko.observable();`).

In the second case (when works), during binding process, knockout updates `programId` (to set default value of select), thus your subscription fires:

```
self.programId.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    self.program(self.availablePrograms()[newValue - 1]);
});
```

So `program` is updated and values are filled correctly.

**Edit:**

Another question appeared:

> what exactly is happening when I select a program? If program() is null, then how is the first input element displaying a value after a program is selected, on the flip side, if program() is not null then how are the other two elements are not being bound?

When knockout binds the first value, exception is thrown (because of undefined) and binding process stops. But this first binding stays "alive", and the rest are just not bound. Just to make it clear - since binding is performed only once, the other fields won't get bound even if `program` value changes. That's why it behaves in such a weird way.

Note: this discussion is copy&pasted from comments to other answer to this same question just to make sure this won't be lost in case that answer is deleted or comments are deleted.

Comment: I am not so sure that is the case. If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/749sj7w5/5/ program is undefined at first, but when a program is selected from the drop down, it is no longer undefined, and thus all three bindings should (theoretically) work, but clearly I am not completely understanding the framework, so I could be off here as well.

Comment: I've explained this in a comment to the second answer. I'll add this explanation to my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your input bindings are attempting to use properties of the object found in the `program` observable.  When you add the caption to the select `options` binding, there is no initial value and thus `program` ends up not having a value (`undefined`) so everything breaks down.

The others have provided a way to work around the problem but another problem still remains, you're not using these bindings to their fullest potential.

The selected value of a `select` element does *not* need to be a string or other simple value, it can be *anything*.  Rather than binding to a supplemental id and looking up the associated program, just bind to the program itself.

```html
<select data-bind="options: availablePrograms,
                   optionsText: 'Description',
                   optionsCaption: 'Select a Program',
                   value: selectedProgram">
</select>
```

```js
function ViewModel() {
  this.selectedProgram = ko.observable();

  this.availablePrograms = ko.observableArray(...);
}
```

Then from there, if you want to access properties of the selected program, change the context to the selected program using the `with` binding.

```html
<div data-bind="with: selectedProgram">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description"/>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description"/>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: ProgramId"/>
</div>
```

Note that this will not display the inputs if there is no selected program.  If you want to keep it visible, use a dummy object if there is no selected program.

```html
<div data-bind="with: selectedProgram() || {}">...</div>
```

Demo:

```js
function Program(programId, description) {
  this.ProgramId = programId;
  this.Description = description;
}


function ViewModel() {
  this.selectedProgram = ko.observable();

  this.availablePrograms = ko.observableArray([
    new Program(1, 'Program One'),
    new Program(2, 'Program Two'),
    new Program(3, 'Program Three')
  ]);
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('content'));
```

```css
#content div {
  border: thin black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <div>
    <select data-bind="options: availablePrograms,
                       optionsText: 'Description',
                       optionsCaption: 'Select a Program',
                       value: selectedProgram">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div data-bind="with: selectedProgram() || {}">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description"/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description"/>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: ProgramId"/>
  </div>
</div>
```